# Vue: Detect when new component is mounted

Tags: vue.js, watch

I'm working on an undo functionality, where a modal pops up in the bottom of the screen after a user clicks the 'delete' button (similar to gmail). Now, I would like to disable the 'delete button' while the undo component is mounted. The undo component and the component where it is shown are unrelated, I am therefore unable to `$emit` events and would like to avoid using an Event Bus. I know that `this.$options.components` holds information on the mounted components - so I am basically looking for way to `watch` changes `$options.components` 
Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watching subcomponents internal properties is not really the Vue way, properties like `$options` are used by plugins and the likes but you should not really use it in your day-to-day code.

Ideally you should have a v-if or an event that links the two but it appears that it is not possible.

Therefore you should share state with [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) and have conditional behavior based on this shared state. Something like:

```
// store.js
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    userCanUndo: false,
  },
  mutations: {
    setUserCanUndo(state, value) {
      state.userCanUndo = value;
    }
  },
}
```

```
// Undo.vue
<template>
  <div v-if="userCanUndo">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['userCanUndo']),
  },
}
</script>
```

```
// DeleteButton.vue
<template>
  <button :disabled="userCanUndo" @click="delete">
    Delete
  </button>
</template>
<script>
import { mapMutations, mapState } from 'vuex';
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['userCanUndo']),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(['setUserCanUndo']),
    delete() {
      // your delete code here
      this.setUserCanUndo(true);
      setTimeout(() => { this.setUserCanUndo(false); }, 2000);
  }
}
```